# Create folder from file in name using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I need help in creating folder. I am pulling up report for Azure subscription which are saved in multiple txt files Eg. 1App.txt, 2App.txt. The report pulled are saved in one folder name Output.

I need to create an folder as per the name of txt files and move files of Output folder to the newly created folder. Also is it possible to put a condition that if subscription is of 1App.txt then files saved in Output should be moved to 1App folder. Also need to put a condition so that it should be able to move files to existing folder when the script is run again.

```
$Folder = 'C:\Scrpting\Subscriptions'
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -File | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
$AzSubs = Get-Content -Path $Files
$AzSubs
$Result = ForEach ($AzSub in $AzSubs) {
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $AzSub

    $Userroles = Get-AzRoleAssignment | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.ObjectType -eq "User" }
    Foreach ($User in $Userroles) {
        $info = "" | Select "DisplayName", "SignInName", "RoleDefinitionName", "SubscriptionName"
        $info.DisplayName = $User.DisplayName
        $info.SignInName = $User.SignInName
        $info.RoleDefinitionName = $User.RoleDefinitionName
        $info.SubscriptionName = $AzSub
        $info | Export-Csv C:\Scrpting\Output\UserRoles$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")).csv -Append
    }
}

ForEach ( $azSub in $azSubs ) {
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $azSub
    $azNsgs = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup
    $Output = ForEach ( $azNsg in $azNsgs ) {
        #Export custom rules
        Get-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -NetworkSecurityGroup $azNsg | `
            Select-Object @{label = 'NSG Name'; expression = { $azNsg.Name } }, `
        @{label = 'NSG Location'; expression = { $azNsg.Location } }, `
        @{label = 'Rule Name'; expression = { $_.Name } }, `
        @{label = 'Source'; expression = { $_.SourceAddressPrefix } }, `
        @{label = 'Source Application Security Group'; expression = { $_.SourceApplicationSecurityGroups.id.Split('/')[-1] } },
        @{label = 'Source Port Range'; expression = { $_.SourcePortRange } }, Access, Priority, Direction, `
        @{label = 'Destination'; expression = { $_.DestinationAddressPrefix } }, `
        @{label = 'Destination Application Security Group'; expression = { $_.DestinationApplicationSecurityGroups.id.Split('/')[-1] } }, `
        @{label = 'Destination Port Range'; expression = { $_.DestinationPortRange } }, `
        @{label = 'Resource Group Name'; expression = { $azNsg.ResourceGroupName } },
        @{label = 'Subscription Name'; expression = { $azSub } } 
    }
    $Output | Export-Csv -Path C:\Scrpting\Output\FirewallRules$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")).csv -Append
}

ForEach ($AzSub in $AzSubs) {
    # change azure subscription
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionID $AzSub
    $vms = Get-AzVM
    $vmrg = Get-AzVM | Select-Object "ResourceGroupName"

    $nics = get-AzNetworkInterface | ? { $_.VirtualMachine -NE $null }
    ForEach ($nic in $nics) {
        $info = "" | Select VMName, ResourceGroupName, OS, PrivateIPAddress, PublicIPAddress, SubscriptionID, Status, NICName
        $vm = $vms | ? -Property Id -eq $nic.VirtualMachine.id
        $info.NICName = $nic.Name
        $info.VMName = $vm.Name
        $info.SubscriptionID = $subscriptionId
        $info.ResourceGroupName = $vm.ResourceGroupName
        $info.PrivateIPAddress = $nic.IpConfigurations.PrivateIpAddress
        $PublicIPAddress = (Az vm list-ip-addresses --name $vm.Name --resource-group $vm.ResourceGroupName | ConvertFrom-Json).virtualMachine.network.publicIpAddresses.ipaddress
        $info.PublicIPAddress = if ($PublicIPAddress -eq $null) { "Not Assigned" } else { $PublicIPAddress }
        $info.OS = $vm.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType
        $info.Status = ((Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $vm.Name -Status).Statuses[1]).code
        $info | Export-Csv -Path C:\Scrpting\Output\VMInfo$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")).csv -Append
    }
}
```

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item?force_isolation=true&view=powershell-7.3#examples

Comment: This does provide information about creating folder but what I need is the folders should be created dynamically. If I add new txt file then script should created folder based on that file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Test-Path` and `New-Item` to conditionally create a folder named for the file's basename:

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem -File){
  # test if folder exists
  if(-not(Test-Path $file.BaseName)){
    # if not, create it!
    New-Item -Name $file.BaseName -ItemType Directory
  }

  # move the file
  $file |Move-Item -Destination $file.BaseName
}
```